# Predicates in ibuffer saved filter groups

Tags: org-mode, ibuffer

How do I add a new [ibuffer](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IbufferMode) saved filter group which matches all files in `org-agenda-files`?

Something like:

```
(setq-default ibuffer-saved-filter-groups
              `(("Default"
                 ("Agenda" (or (mode . org-agenda-mode)
                               (mode . diary-mode)
                               (predicate . '(lambda ()
                                              (member (buffer-file-name)
                                                      (mapcar 'expand-file-name org-agenda-files))))))))
```

I'm guessing at the `predicate` bit as I can't find any examples or documentation. What should it really look like?

Comment: Don't quote your lambdas!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The predicate is not a function, but a form to be eval'd in the context of each buffer

Something like this should work:

```
(defun my-org-agenda-filter ()
  (let ((fname (buffer-file-name)))
    (and fname
         (member (file-truename fname)
                 (mapcar 'file-truename (org-agenda-files))))))

(setq-default ibuffer-saved-filter-groups
              `(("default"
                 ("Agenda" (or (mode . org-agenda-mode)
                               (mode . diary-mode)
                               (predicate . (my-org-agenda-filter)))))))
```

Note that you should not use `org-agenda-files` since it can be for example a directory, or even a file containing the list of actual files you're interested in.

Comment: Your `my-org-agenda-filter` isn't working for me: no buffers end up in the Agenda group. Using my original strategy but with your new layout (separate function, check for fname) works though. Does this work on your machine? My `org-agenda-files` is a list of files, but for future readers it would be good if `org-agenda-file-p` worked.

Comment: @BufferMangler indeed, actually I think my previous implementation worked (I just reverted to it) and I modified it when I saw `org-agenda-file-p` existed... which is buggy (it doesn't normalize filenames). I guess I should submit a patch. Can you verify if it works for you?